# Dakṣa’s illicit relations with his daughter

Tags: skanda-purana, daksha

In Daksha yagna chapter translation of [Skanda Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc365950.html#note-e-127662), the footnote says:

> The legend of destruction of Dakṣa’s sacrifice is mentioned in the Śatapatha and Kauṣītaki Brāhmaṇas. But the cause was Dakṣa’s illicit relations with his daughter.

Please can someone explain more on this  relationship with his daughter. Who is that daughter, what sort of relationship and why, what were the consequences of it.

Comment: There’s already an existing question on this : [Does the Shatapatha Brahmana actually discuss Daksha Yajna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48863/does-the-satapatha-brahmana-actually-discuss-shiva-and-the-daksha-yajna)

Comment: I didn’t know about this till today. I had no idea that this had happen :( I have really connected to the stories of Sati & Parvati and this is quite horrible if Sati went through this experience. No wonder she had so much anger and reacted the way she did. I guess this parallel w/ the Brahma-Sarasvati stories of the same nature. Thx for making a post about this @Kanthri