# Does Hinduism encourage incest?

Tags: puranas

I have heard a few stories about the deity brahma and saraswati. I felt disappointed and I hope it is not true.I hope incest is wrong(incest between daughter and father,brother and sister, and mother and son)is strictly against the law of nature and shouldn't be encouraged in any religion.

Comment: Please check this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/598/did-lord-brahma-commit-incest-with-his-daughter

Comment: Although there are `Dharma Shāstras` in Hinduism, most of their sayings are nearly impossible to follow today (because of Yuga & modernization) therefore `Hinduism` believes more in developing `Conscience` in you to discriminate between right & wrong with the help of scriptures, gurus & works of our āchāryas rather than parroting sayings of scriptures.

Comment: Bramha was punished for that sin.

Comment: @Yogi but still how did saraswati end up as wife of Brahma? If it's a sin.

Comment: @Anisha she is not really his daughter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**NO.** It does not.

Incest is one of the grave sins in Hinduism.

Here are few verses from the Manu Smriti :

> 11.58. **Carnal intercourse with sisters by the same  mother**, with (unmarried) maidens, with females of the  lowest castes, with the
>   wives of a friend, **or of a son, they  declare to be equal to the
>   violation of a Guru’s bed**
>
> 11.170. **He who has had sexual intercourse with sisters  by the same mother**, with the wives of a friend, or of a son, with unmarried
>   maidens, and with females of the  lowest castes, **shall perform the
>   penance, prescribed  for the violation of a Guru’s bed.**
>
> 11.171. **He who has approached the daughter of his  father’s sister, (who is almost equal to) a sister,  (the daughter) of his mother’s
>   sister, or of his mother’s  full brother, shall perform a lunar
>   penance.**

And, violation of Guru's bed is one of the mahapatakas or mortal sins in Hinduism as stated in the following verse:

> Manu Smriti 9.235. The slayer of a Brahmana, (A twice-born man) who
>   drinks (the spirituous liquor called) Sura, he who steals (the gold of
>   a Brahmana), **and he who violates a Guru’s bed, must each and all be
>   considered as men who committed mortal sins (mahapataka).**

And here a few verses from the **Parashara Smriti's chapter 10**:

> [image]
>
> 9. **If a person, bereft of all sense, cohabits with his mother, or sister, or self-begotten daughter, he must  perform a three-fold
>      Krichchhra penance** ; a tire-fold  Chandrayana should also be performed
>      ; **he must,  likewise, cut off his male organ.**
> 10. **On cohabitation with a mother's sister, it is  requisite to cut off the male organ ;** but if it has been done  unwittingly, the sinner
>       must perform a double  Chandrayana. He must give ten couples of
>       cattle, each couple to consist  of a female and a male, as fee : this
>       is the expiation as  declared by Parasara.
> 11. **On sexual union with a father's wife, or a near  relative of the mother, or a brother's daughter, or the  preceptor's wife, a son's
>       wife, or the wife of a brother, or the wife of a brother of the
>       mother, or any woman of the same  gotra, a three-fold Prajapatya is
>       the expiation prescribed** ; a  couple of cattle is the fee to be given.
>       Thus the sinner undoubtedly gets rid of his sin.

So, as you can see, such sins are quite grave and the expiation measures are quite severe too.