# What is the greatest sin in Hinduism. According to vedas

Tags: vedas, sin

Is eating beef greatest sin. Not worshipping God is greatest sin. Or some thing else.

Comment: There is the concept of 5 great sins in Hinduism. See [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19611/what-are-the-panch-maha-paap/19613#19613) . There you can get one reference from one Upanishad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Papa and Punya is not defined in absolute term. Gita in Ch.4 solka 17 says गहना कर्मणोगति (The intricacies of action are very hard to understand.).
As an example read the story of Mandavya in Mahabharat ([here](http://unclekatha.com/?p=100)). Even the great Rishi is punished for a small trivial action.
Vyasa knows the best. He says:
"Ashtadasa Puraneshu Vyasena Vachanam Dwayam, Paropakaraya Punyaya – Papaya Para Peedanam". Meaning: Two important sentence of Vyasa which can be the essence of 18 puranas are “helping others is punya and hurting others is papa”.

Comment: If you don’t know where this shloka appears, how can the answer say it was said by Vyasa and where was t said by him. Let this question be answered first https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43948/there-does-this-shloka-appear then you could post this as an answer

Comment: Mandavya risihu was not punished for killing insect according to MBTN of sirman madhvaacharya he is punished for aspiring to become sage vasista with his penance that is wrong same case sambhuka in ramayana where he aspired to become siva himself so that he can get sri parvati devi. But only differerence  is Rishi is not out of lust. But despite being all knowing Rishi he did penance which have got wrong motive @Kaushik

Comment: If you mean papa is not defined/described in Vedas, then do mention it clearly. Also since the question is looking for greatest sin, need to answer that in specific way.