# Where does this shloka appear?

Tags: shloka

Where does this shloka appear?

"Astadasa Puranesu Vyasena Vachanam Dwayam, Paropakaraya Punyaya – Papaya Para Peedanam"

Answer (score 1):

This appears to a subhāṣita (wise saying), listed as [No. 3587 in the Mahā-Subhāṣita-Saṅgraha](https://archive.org/stream/MahaasubhaasitasamgrahaVol1-8/Mahaasubhaasitasamgraha_Vol_2#page/n375/mode/2up). This collection in turn references other subhāṣita collections as its source so it probably doesn't belong to any Hindu scripture.

> **3587**
>
> अष्टादशपुराणेषु व्यासस्य वचनद्वयम् । 
> परोपकारः पुण्याय पापाय परपीडनम् ॥
>
> aṣṭādaśapurāṇeṣu vyāsasya vacanadvayam | 
> paropakāraḥ puṇyāya pāpāya parapīḍanam ||
>
> [Secondary Sources:]
>
> Subhāṣita-saptaśati 697, Saṃskṛta-sūktiratnākara 970, Subhāṣita-padya-ratnākara 753. 12 (a. Bhāgavata).
>
> [Meaning:]
>
> In the course of the eighteen Purāṇas, the sage Vyāsa has made two (very fine) statements: doing help to others results in religious merit, doing injury to others brings about sin. (A. A. R.).