# Punishment of intercourse between children below 13 or 12?

Tags: sex, punishment, kama

I saw some children who were siblings and still they were doing sexual activity even though they were kids and their big friends told them to do so, are they still punishable according to Sanatan Dharma?

I know they surely didn't generated kama but surely any other desire, are they punishable?
If they are what are their punishment?

Comment: Incest is considered as a grave sin in Hinduism .. for this point see the answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18531/4732

Comment: BTW do you mean the kids didn't know what they were actually doing?

Comment: Actually I already read your answer earlier, but the thing is, it is written about a full grown person and those were kids their organs were also not developed, how can we call it as sexual intercourse. Even though I saw the boy penetrating his tool inside girl, but a small boy can't develop sexual emotion if he wants. Does it still considered as sexual intercourse, is it still punishable?

Comment: Well if the boy knows that much then we can't call him a kid. They were fully aware of what they were doing. I think some people get sexual maturity earlier than others so age is not the factor. If they were aware of what they were doing and if they were enjoying the act then it's incest.

Comment: well that is my point, they were not enjoying it neither know what is tends to, just some big boys told him to do so, and he did the same, it is almost 7 years from now when I ask that kid about all this he is still ashamed of what he did

Comment: Okay ... then Im not sure.

Comment: Do you know what he should do, to purify his soul ?

Comment: From what you have said he was not aware of what he was actually doing and plus he was not enjoying the act .. so according to me there is no guilt involved.

Comment: Can you tell me the vedic criteria to called any act as incest ?

Comment: Vedic criteria --- I did not understand

Comment: In vedas, what is the exact situation that we can in every case call as incest

Comment: Not sure about Vedas but in Hinduism, sex between persons belonging to the same Gotra is prohibited like incest. Sex between blood relatives fall under great sins. In Rig Veda we fin a story of how Yami, the sister of Yama, tries to persuade him into incest but Yama refuses. But as I have said, the persons involved here were not matured enough to either understand what they were doing nor they have enjoyed. So there is no guilt and no need to purify according to me